# Why TFTP use its own protocol on top of UDP

Tags: networking

The TFTP protocol is built on top of UDP. For the sake of data integrity why do they use UDP while TCP is out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>>TFTP is designed to be used during a bootstrap phase when only ...
```

Actually it is the other way around;

The **Trivial File Transfer Protocol** (TFTP) standard [RFC 783](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc783) was published in **1981** and the **Bootstrap Loading using TFTP standard** [RFC 906](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc906) was published in **1984**.

RFC 906 is considered the first standard describing how to bootstrap a computer system from a communications network.

UDP was used in TFTP because it was the simplest transport available. From RFC 783:

> 1. Purpose
>
> TFTP  is  a simple protocol to transfer files, and therefore was
> named
> the Trivial File Transfer Protocol or TFTP.  It has been implemented
> on
> top  of  the Internet User Datagram protocol (UDP or Datagram) so
> it
> may be used  to  move  files  between  machines  on  different
> networks
> implementing   UDP.     (This  should  not  exlude  the  possibility
> of
> implementing TFTP on top of other datagram protocols.)  It  is
> designed
> to  be  small  and  easy  to implement.  Therefore, it lacks most of
> the
> features of a regular FTP.
>
> ...

Answer (score 6):

TFTP is designed to be used during a bootstrap phase when only a minimal amount of code is running, possibly not even including TCP.